# Changing the position of watched tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

**Problem**

I have added 17 tags in the ***Watched Tags*** section. and by default, all tags are sorted by their names.

from all my tags, I want 2 or 3 tags to appear at the beginning. so that whenever I want to watch specific tags I can directly get them from the first sight instead of finding it every time from the list.

**Solution**

If changing the position of tags when we click and drag any tag is implemented then this problem can be solved.

This can be an addition to the user experience.

Comment: [Userscripts save the day, again](https://stackapps.com/questions/8030/reorderable-favorite-tags-drag-drop-ordering-for-the-watched-tag-sidebar)